# Kernel update breaks CUDA

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I have a NVIDIA Grid K2 GPU allocated to a virtual server running Ubuntu 14.04. To reinstall the proper drivers after an automatic kernel update I ran `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.

Now I cannot get CUDA 7.5 to work any longer. If I run the deviceQuery sample I get the following message:

```
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL
```

This is the output from `sudo lshw -c video`

```
PCI (sysfs)

  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: SVGA II Adapter
       vendor: VMware
       physical id: f
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0f.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=vmwgfx latency=64
       resources: irq:16 ioport:1070(size=16) memory:ec000000-efffffff memory:fe000000-fe7fffff memory:c0300000-c0307fff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK104GL [GRID K2]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=64
       resources: irq:19 memory:fc000000-fcffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e9ffffff ioport:5000(size=128)
```

Comment: `nvidia-current` is almost certainly not the correct package to use.  Follow the steps to [clean out old package manager installations](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#handle-uninstallation) (i.e. "Use the following commands to uninstall a RPM/Deb installation").  Be sure to clean out all packages that were installed by `nvidia-current` as well as any that were part of the previous CUDA and driver installation.  Then follow [the steps to (re)install CUDA 7.5](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation).

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming your previous (original?) CUDA 7.5 install was done via the package manager method.  If it was actually done via the runfile installer method, then the recovery steps are somewhat different.  But I would refer you to the [same section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#handle-uninstallation) of the installation guide.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites, either http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertCrovella - that worked perfectly!

Comment: @shellter: I could perhaps close it now that it's been solved. However, it might be useful to future readers? The main problem regarding posting the wrong questions on SO is that I've tried asking similar questions on askubuntu.com or unix.stackexchange.com, but I never get any replies. It seems that users on SO are more friendly towards my "stupid" Linux questions. It's slightly annoying with the other sites as I do try to make an effort to solve the problem and document my actions.

Comment: @felbo why don't you add an answer explaining what you did.  I would upvote.   Then we can get this question off the unanswered list.  If it happens to get closed, so be it.

Comment: Thanks. I've added an answer now. Feel free to edit it if I'm unclear in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue with the following steps using the hints from the [installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#handle-uninstallation):

1. Uninstalled the packages that I had mistakenly installed by running `sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current`.
2. Uninstalled CUDA 7.5 with the command `sudo /usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/uninstall_cuda_7.5.pl`
3. Restarted the server using `sudo reboot`
4. Installed CUDA 7.5 by running [the downloadable .run file](http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda) and following the instructions.
5. Checking that everything works by running the deviceQuery CUDA sample.